# How to manage memory in functions C++

Tags: c++, function, memory

How to manage memory in function, which returns dynamically allocated variable?
What happens with buffer, when function returns?

```
char * getStr(){

    char * buffer = new char[12];
    sprintf_s(buffer, 12 , "abcdef");

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: in `c`, AFAIK , `new` is not there.

Comment: Please tag your question as either C or C++, not both. In C, you use `malloc` for dynamic memory, while in C++ you use `new`.

Comment: Maybe its time to learn std::string instead of using c strings in c++.

Comment: I've changed my queston.
So you say that it's incorrect to use char in c++?
I know what is std::string.
But I always was interested what happens with buffer in my case.

Comment: People are answering your question well, but in c++ we try to avoid passing suff like this. It is better to return a std::string (which owns and manages its own memory) than to trigger the above situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer` stays allocated, but luckily you're returning the pointer.

You **must** `delete[]` that pointer at some point, else you'll leak memory.

Notice how I've used `[]`: that's important. This balances your allocation of an *array* of `char`s. (Conceptually the runtime stores the length of an array allocated with `new something[]`, and `delete[]` informs the runtime to free the correct number of elements.)

Answer (score 1):

When function returns, your buffer still exists. There is nothing like embedded memory manager, you MUST free all the memory you allocated manualy. That is about C.

In C++ standart library, there is objects called smart pointers. With the pressence of exceptions, they are totally recommended to use. There is fine answer on SO about them: [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

The address which is stored in `*buffer` will be returned to the caller and it is up to the caller to `delete` the memory again.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is a pointer that means it addresses a point in memory.

`new` will allocate a bloc of memory, for the command `new char[12]` it will allocate 12 `char`s worth of memory.

`new` returns the address of the memory and that is assigned to your pointer `buffer`.

Note that because you only have a pointer to the memory, you need to clean that up before `buffer` goes out of scope. If the address contained in buffer `buffer` goes out of scope you will have "leaked" memory. Because it cannot be reclaimed. You clean up the memory allocated by `new char[12]` with the command: `delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27402995/4305062).

My vision of a solution to the problem:

```
char * getStr(){

    char * buffer = new char[12];
    sprintf_s(buffer, 12 , "abcdef");

    return buffer;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    char * p = getStr();

    std::cout << p << std::endl;

    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```